Opening MS Calculator in Windows 10 Opens Edge
I have Windows 10 Home and MS Calculator pinned to my taskbar.

If I left-click on the icon, it opens the calculator normally.

If I right-click and try to open it with any of the "Tasks", MS Edge also opens at the same time.

If I right-click and only select "Calculator", that opens without Edge.


Here's a screenshot of the menu:

Bracket is what I mean by the "Tasks" and the red arrow is what I mean by only "Calculator".
How do I make Windows stop opening Edge when I open the calculator?

I was only able to partially replicate the behavior you describe,  I was present this which typically is due to file association being set. I have written numerous answers about similar problems with various UWP applications over the years. DISM will be unable to resolve this particular problem.  I am unable to Reset the calculator on the Windows 10 installation I am using. When I first performed the steps, the Tasks were just a path to the UWP application, but once I clicked on one of them the tasks name were filled.

This is one of those answers. It's not applicable to Windows 10, but describes the same exact problem, which is the reason I believe just performing a Reset on Calculator would work.
